# 言語の省略名からフルネームを取得する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

各ユーザーの言語設定について`User.lang` で `:en` や `:ja`などの省略名のシンボルを返すようにしています。

この時ユーザの言語設定が日本語なら`en`を`イギリス`に、英語なら`English`に変えるために

#### config/locales/ja.yml

```
ja:
  en: 'イギリス'
```

#### config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  en: 'English`
```

のように記述してるのですが、全ての国に対応させるのが少々手間で、またこの機能はそれなりに汎用性もあると思うのですが
これらを上手くとりあつかえる`gem`や、もしくはRailsの関数などはありますか？

#### 国名と言語名が区別されていなかったので修正しました。

言語の省略名を扱うGemとして以下の二つが見つかりましたが、省略名から指定した言語での言語のフルネームを取得できないようでした。

https://github.com/alphabetum/iso-639

https://github.com/scsmith/language_list

Comment: 国名と言語名が混同されているようですので、質問内容を変更した方が良いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。修正しました。

Answer (score 1):

国に関するデータを扱う [hexorx/countries](https://github.com/hexorx/countries) という gem があります